# Why would a query activity fail where a manual import or filter work?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql

I am currently trying to run a query which selects all records where the Job_Ref column contains 'MSI_13628_HIS_NCC_X1' (a job number). It does not find the full amount of people. For example, there should be 4,500 records - something I verified by filtering the source data extension.

Then when I write the query to

```
SELECT * FROM MASTER WHERE Job_Ref = 'MSI_13628_HIS_NCC_X1'
```

I get 0 results.

So I thought, maybe a column in my target data extension is set up wrong, perhaps a character limit issue?

But then I tried a manual import of this data from a CSV, and it imported all 4,500 records.

So is there a reason that a data extension will fail to populate via a query when a manual import of the same data, or a data filter on the source, would succeed?

Comment: Did you check the action log on the query to make sure it didn't fail? I usually run queries inside of Automations to keep track of run time and status.

Comment: Yes - they succeeded every time. I've also just noticed the source data extension I was filtering is a non-sendable, and my target was sendable. So I checked the people it was ignoring and guess what? They're all either non-existent as contacts (or have been purged in a Contact Delete we recently had) or they're unsubscribed). So is the query really checking their subscriber status for me? If so, that's incredibly useful.

Comment: I can't definitively say no, but I have never experienced that before. do you have it set to overwrite? for some reason on the first run, I need to have the action set to 'Update' to fill in the DE, then switch back to update after that. It is a rare bug in SFMC queries.